# Passing content as parameter to tag file

Tags: jsf, parameter-passing, facelets, tagfile

i want to pass the content for a link to my tag file

```
<custom:link>
 <f:param name="linkContent">
  <h:graphicImage value="/images/img.gif" width="15" />
 </f:param> 
</custom:link>
```

my `link.xhtml`:

```
<a4j:commandLink>
    #{linkContent}
</a4j:commandLink>
```

how can I archieve something linke that? the var `linkContent` keeps empty

Comment: Please be careful with terminology. This is not a custom component, but a composite component. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen

Comment: Now it turns out to be a tag file. I edited the question again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define it as [`<ui:define>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/define.html) and insert it as [`<ui:insert>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/insert.html):

```html
<custom:link>
    <ui:define name="linkContent">
        <h:graphicImage value="/images/img.gif" width="15" />
    </ui:define>
</custom:link>
```

```html
<a4j:commandLink>
    <ui:insert name="linkContent" />
</a4j:commandLink>
```

Comment: hm sounds complicated, isn't i more easy to create an ui:composition?

Comment: What is the `<custom:link>` then? You said "custom component", but then you said "link.xhtml" so it can impossibly be a custom component, so I assumed that it's a composite component as that's what most beginners really mean when they say "custom component". But now it seems to be not a composite component as well. Is it a plain tag file then? Please read the link which I posted in the comment on your question.

Comment: it is defined as <facelet-taglib>, i'll try your solution later thanks

Comment: Not helpful. Composite components and custom components can also be declared in there.